# What run flags are included in my Docker Container

Tags: docker

I started a docker container (using docker run). I can see it in my Kitematic app. When I start it from Kitematic, I'm sure it's reusing my flags, like -P to expose ports.

How can I see what flags the container is using? For example, I forget what directory/volume I mounted to the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try first to look at the result of [`docker inspect`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/inspect/):

```
docker inspect yourContainerNameOrId
```

docker inspect has an elaborate template-base format, explained in "[Docker Inspect Template Magic](http://container-solutions.com/docker-inspect-template-magic/)", written by [Adrian Mouat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4332/adrian-mouat).

For instance, to [get the port mapping of a container](https://github.com/wsargent/docker-cheat-sheet#get-port-mapping):

```
docker inspect -f '{{range $p, $conf := .NetworkSettings.Ports}} {{$p}} -> {{(index $conf 0).HostPort}} {{end}}' <containername>
```

Comment: I figured this out and came back to delete my question. But your answer got here before me so I will accept it as soon as SO lets me. Thx!

Comment: @kane no problem. It might help others.